# How to create (not equals or not equals or not ..etc) query in sql

Tags: mysql

i am using mySql server ,and i have this table:
Student(studentId, studentName, section)
column section can be filled by either (A,B,c,d,e ,....or z)

what i want is to retrieve  all rows that is not in section a or b or c 
my problem is how to write not equals or not equals ... multiple time in where clause

this is my try but it does not work properly

```
SELECT studentName, section
FROM Student
WHERE section <> 'a'OR section <> 'b' or section <> 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE column NOT IN('A', 'b', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Where section not in('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is the `OR`. You want to be using `AND` instead. The reason is that every record will **always** match one of those conditions, because it can't possibly be all three (or even two) of the values you're checking inequality against.

An even better option would be to use the `IN` clause, specifically `NOT IN`, to specify a list of items to match against. i.e. `WHERE section NOT IN ('a','b','c')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE section NOT IN ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT studentName, section
FROM Student
WHERE section <> 'a' and section <> 'b' and section <> 'c'
```

or

```
SELECT studentName, section
FROM Student
WHERE section not in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```